# Function works only sometimes. How could this be?

Tags: javascript

In my snake game I am trying to catch the **y-coordinate** of a rectangle (food).

Now check out this function:

```
function eat() { 
    console.log('food_x:' + food_position_x + ' x:' + x + ' / food_y:' + food_position_y + ' y:' + y);
    if (y == food_position_y) {       
        throw new Error("MATCH!"); // This is not an error. Just trying to stop the script
    }
}
```

Pretty simple, huh?

Now the weird thing about this story is: `y` is not always equal `food_position_y`!

You may want to check the full script:

```
(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      x = 0,
      y = 0,
      speed = 2; 
      x_move = speed,
      y_move = 0,                          
      food_position_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
      food_position_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

  function eat() { 
    console.log('food_x:' + food_position_x + ' x:' + x + ' / food_y:' + food_position_y + ' y:' + y);
    if (y == food_position_y) {       
      throw new Error("MATCH!"); // This is not an error. Just trying to stop the script
    }
  }

  // Drawing
  function draw() {
    eat();
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {      
      draw();      
    });    
    // Draw the snake
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(Math.floor(x/10)*10, Math.floor(y/10)*10, 10, 10);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'; 
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    // Draw the food
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.rect(Math.floor(food_position_x/10)*10, Math.floor(food_position_y/10)*10, 10, 10);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    // Increase the value of x and y in order to animate
    x = x + x_move;
    y = y + y_move;       
  } 
  draw();

  // Key Pressing
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
      case 40: // Moving down
        if (x_move != 0 && y_move != -1) {
          x_move = 0;
          y_move = speed;
        }
      break;
      case 39: // Moving right
        if (x_move != -1 && y_move != 0) {
          x_move = speed;
          y_move = 0; 
        }
      break;
      case 38: // Moving top
        if (x_move != 0 && y_move != 1) {
          x_move = 0;
          y_move = -speed; 
        }
      break;
      case 37: // Moving left
        if (x_move != 1 && y_move != 0) {
          x_move = -speed;
          y_move = 0; 
        }
      break;
    }
  });
})();
```

What do I mean by "`y` is not always equal `food_position_y`"?

Please go ahead and make yourself an impression of it. Try to run [this script](https://jsfiddle.net/pvnLvhfq/) a multiple times.

For now, don't worry about `x`. Just try to catch the food and you will notice, that sometimes you will get an "error" (which is good!) and the game stops but sometimes when the snake is even on the same height as the food, you won't get this fancy error and the game goes on.

Question: **Why?**

Comment: *What do I mean by "`y` is not always equal `food_position_y`"? Please go ahead and make yourself an impression of it.* Sorry but that doesn't answer your question. Just tell us why/when/where you think they should be equal. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `speed` is 2, and so the `y` value is always an even number. Meanwhile, `food_position_y` is sometimes an odd number, so it's impossible for them to meet when that happens.

Comment: @4castle thank you for this info! I have set `speed` to `1` and it works great. But what do I have to change if I want the speed to be `2`?

Comment: `if (Math.abs(y - food_position_y) < speed) {`

Answer (score 0):

As 4castle explained,

The amount it is moving is dictated by speed.  Speed is set to 2.  If the y coordinate for the "snake" is an odd number, then it will be incremented by two each time and will never reach the same y-coordinate for the "food" (if food is even).  A way to see this is to switch the speed to 1.  This of course will make your snake move at half speed, so after you visually see your program working - switch back to speed = 2 and tweak the food's y-coordinate variable to be an odd number as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at the console output, because it shows the culprit:

> food_x:31 x:34 / food_y:**97** y:**98**
>   food_x:31 x:34 / food_y:**97** y:**96**

Your snake is just never on the same exact position as the food. The `eat()` function is called every time. However, your condition isn't always true.

The solution to this problem would be to just check if `y` *somewhat equal* (within tolerance of `speed`) to `food_position_y`:

```
if (Math.abs(y - food_position_y) <= Math.abs(speed)) {
    throw;
}
```